# Periodically fetch Facebook like,share and comment count for all pages within domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

We are to create a statistics module for our news portal which involves crawling like and share count for each article (~7000 urls and continuously increasing).

The statistics is to be regenerated at least daily and without user iteraction.

We tried using fql without access_token (as it would involve user iteraction):

- select ... from link_stat where url = ...
- select ... from link_stat where url IN (...,...,...)
- same with multiquery

But we are getting 403 Forbidden response after a few requests and the actual ip "banned" (all other requests without access_token result in 403) for some time.

Is there a proper way of collecting like and share counts for the particullar website?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to query facebook using FQL is to install the "fbcmd" app. This app lets you access the facebook and execute FQL statements from command line. It needs authorization once, during installation. After that, you can execute any number of queries.